# how to use sonata media bundle with my entities

Tags: symfony-sonata

I want to use sonata media bundle for medias in my bundle.

I have one entity which should have a gallery. After installing sonata media bundle and generating easy:extends, there are 3 diffrent entities:

- Media.php
- Gallery.php
- GalleryHasMedia.php.

How can I link these entities to my own entity for gallery implementation???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the documentation about the implementation:

http://sonata-project.org/blog/2013/10/11/mediabundle-mediatype-improved

Answer (score 4):

You can link one-to-one.
for example, my implementation:

config.yml:

```
contexts:
        product:
            providers:
                - sonata.media.provider.image

            formats:
                big:   { width: 1680 , quality: 100}
```

Gallery.php:

```
private $product;
```

Gallery.orm.xml:

```
<one-to-one field="product" target-entity="Alteza\ProductBundle\Entity\Product" inversed-by="gallery">
        <join-column name="product_id" referenced-column-name="id" />
    </one-to-one>
```

Product.php:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Gallery", mappedBy="product", cascade={"all"})
 */
private $gallery;
```

ProductAdmin.php:

```
->add('gallery', 'sonata_type_model_list', array('required' => false), array('link_parameters'   => array('context' => 'product')))
```

Comment: From where comes the product contexts?